# I'm trying to use gson on Java to write a large list of custom objects to a json file, but it cuts off before the file's finished?

Tags: java, gson

I am making a Java program to read from MTGJson, by saving each card as a custom class, then writing all those cards to another JSON file using gson. (I found that I could not read from mtgjson using gson, but I could with json.simple.) It appears that the code reads the objects in a strange order, then doesn't save every card onto the list, then before the whole list is written in json, it suddenly cuts off. Download for the json file is here.
https://www.mtgjson.com/json/AllSets.json

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseTrimmer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        JSONObject ALLSETS = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("AllSets.json"));
        List<MTGCard> AllCards = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object o: ALLSETS.values()) {
            JSONObject set = (JSONObject)o;
            JSONArray cards = (JSONArray) (set.get("cards"));
            for (Object card : cards) {
                MTGCard tempCard = new MTGCard((JSONObject) card);
                if (!tempCard.isReprint) {
                    AllCards.add(tempCard);
                }
            }
        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("TrimmedAllSets.json");
        gson.toJson(AllCards, writer);
    }
}
```

The last card to be saved to the AllCards list is "Volrath's Motion Sensor", which is the last card of a certain set but not the last set alphabetically. The MTGCard class stores many properties of each card, like name and text. The end of the output json looks like this:

```
"isReprint":false,"printings":["UGL"]},{"name":"Sorry","type":"Enchantment","text":"Before any player casts a spell with the same name as a card in any graveyard, that player may say \"sorry.\" If they don\u0027t, any other player may say \"sorry\" as the spell is being cast. When another player says \"sorry\" this way, counter the spell.\nWhenever a player says \"sorry\" at any other time, Sorry deals 2 damage to that player.","rarity":"uncommon","manaCost":"{U}{U}","artist":"Kaja Foglio","convertedManaCost":2.0,"isFoil":false,"isReprint":false,"printings":["UGL"]},{"name":"Spark Fiend","type":"Creature — Beast","text":"When Spark Fiend enters the battlefield, roll two six-sided dice. If you rolled 2, 3, or 12, sacrifice Spark Fiend. If you rolled 7 or 11, don\u0027t roll dice for Spark Fiend during any of your following upkeeps. If you rolled any other total, note that total.\nAt the beginning of your upkeep, roll two six-sided dice. If you rolled 7, sacrifice Spark Fiend. If you roll the noted total, don\u0027t roll dice for Spark Fiend during any of your
```

As you see, it just cuts off. I looked up anything about gson write limits but couldn't find anything. Also, I tried to make the code start from another point, or read a smaller section, but it still cuts off arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

The program exits before the buffer in the writer is flushed to the operating system. You should `flush` the writer or `close`() it properly.

Answer (score 0):

First convert to string and then save in file is helping me -

```
String allCardsString = gson.toJson(AllCards, writer);
File file = new File("TrimmedAllSets.json");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
fileOutputStream.write(allCardsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```